# Internal Error 500 An error has occurred on Azure portal but locally it works fine

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function which take some parameters and creates a request to another API. In the local Visual Studio, it works fine but it does not work on Azure portal, though the code is the same.

I have inspected all the code with local and Azure portal but don't understand what I am doing wrong. Here is my code snippet.

```
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    try
    {
        // Convert all request perameter into Json object

        var content = req.Content;
        string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        dynamic requestPram = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CaseRequestModel>(jsonContent);


        // Validate required param

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestPram.email.Trim()))
        {
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "email required!");
        }


        //Create API request

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


        //Partner contact class
        Contact objContactModel = new Contact();

        //Call Contact API by Email
        HttpRequestMessage newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://APIURL/api/ConnectUs/GetPartnerContacts?email={0}", requestPram.email.Trim()));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(newRequest);

        List<Contact> listPartnerContact = new List<Contact>();

        //Read Server Response
        listPartnerContact = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Contact>>();

        if (listPartnerContact == null)
        {
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "No Partner found!");
        }

        //Filter one record for binding class for Request Case

        var filterCasePartnerClass = listPartnerContact.FirstOrDefault();

        if (filterCasePartnerClass == null)
        {
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "No Partner found!");
        }
        // Instancify PartnerCaseApiRequestModel class for submitting Case Request

        CaseApiRequestModel caseRequestModel = new CaseApiRequestModel();

        caseRequestModel.serviceCatalog = Guid.NewGuid();
        caseRequestModel.dispatchToTeam = Guid.NewGuid();
        caseRequestModel.title = requestPram.title;
        caseRequestModel.description = requestPram.description;
        caseRequestModel.contact = filterCasePartnerClass;

        // Post data to Partner Case Request API
        // Convert json
        string routingActivityId = null;
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(caseRequestModel);
        var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseFromCaseApi = await client.PostAsync("MyURL", stringContent);

            if (responseFromCaseApi.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                routingActivityId = responseFromCaseApi.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }


        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new CaseResponseModel { CaseRequestId = routingActivityId });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "");
    }
}
```

```
public class CaseResponseModel
{
    public string CaseRequestId { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Contact
{
    public string contactId { get; set; }
    public string mpnID { get; set; }
    public string partnerName { get; set; }
    public string contract { get; set; }
    public DateTime enrollmentEndDate { get; set; }
    public string advisoryHours { get; set; }
    public string fieldMotion { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int contactLanguageCode { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class CaseRequestModel
{

    public string email { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

}
```

```
public class CaseApiRequestModel
{
    public Guid serviceCatalog { get; set; }
    public Guid dispatchToTeam { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can use `log` to log the error information to understand what's not right.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Here is my log {
  "id": "68c755c4-bbd9-4bfb-aada-07bdd67109f3",
  "requestId": "85c1cccf-abe9-4204-bf5f-2d7c63d421ad",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "An error has occurred. For more information, please check the logs for error ID 68c755c4-bbd9-4bfb-aada-07bdd67109f3"
}

Comment: You should make sure that the Newtonsoft assembly is being copies to the build output and ships with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seems you are trying to implement your local function on `azure portal`.

In your case , all the code seems okay. But local visual studio function and `azure portal` has little change.

Remember to add this reference below while migrate to `azure portal`

```cs
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
```

You have also missed following reference 
:

```cs
using System.Text;
```

As you are using

```cs
 var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Which requires above reference.

**Good Practice While Transfer Local Function to Azure Portal**

*1. Do not copy and paste the full code from local to `Azure portal`*

*2. Transfer small chunk of code and `Save & Run`*

*3. If each chunk works well then move to next chunk*

*4. Do not add the class file as .csx first, add class below the
    function once it works fine then add as .csx on file section*

*5. Be care about local reference a to `Azure portal`*

*6. Above practice definitely reduced your error occurrence rate.*

> **Note:** `Local visual studio function` and `Azure portal` has little difference.You should better create new function first. Latter can
>   enhance according to your needs which may reduce error.

If you still have any query feel to share in comment. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Its solved and working as I expected.

Comment: @DotNetFreak Glad to hear, Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: you need to change this `string jsonContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` to `await` .....  using `.Result` is bad practice, especially since you are inside of an `async` method